# Cursor inside cursor and how pass variable

Tags: plsql

I need to make two cursors or one cursor and a loop. But one must be inside other. I'm trying with two cursors and with a for but don't recognize me the variable value of name table of the outside cursor.
Could you help me? Could you suggest me the best way to do these? I'm newbie with pl/sql. Thanks. I put the code:

```
DECLARE
  TABLENAME VARCHAR2(30);
  LINK VARCHAR2(30);

  CURSOR FIRST_SELECT IS
    SELECT A.TABLE_NAME AS TABLENAME, B.LINK AS LINK  
    FROM ALL_TABLES A, TABLE_CONNECT_LINK B 
    WHERE A.TABLE_NAME=B.COMPARE_TABLE;

BEGIN
  OPEN FIRST_SELECT;
  LOOP
    FETCH FIRST_SELECT INTO TABLENAME,LINK;
    EXIT WHEN FIRST_SELECT%NOTFOUND;

    DECLARE
      PEPELU VARCHAR2(4000);
      TABLE VARCHAR2(70);
      stringconsult VARCHAR2(4000);
      COMPONENTE NUMBER(5);
      TABLE_INSERTAR VARCHAR2(30);
      COLUMN VARCHAR2(30);
      OWNER VARCHAR2(30);

      CURSOR ALL IS
        SELECT TABLE,COLUMN,OWNER FROM TABLENAME;

    BEGIN
      OPEN ALL;
      LOOP
        FETCH ALL INTO TABLE,COLUMN,OWNER;
        EXIT WHEN ALL%NOTFOUND;
            stringconsult:='select ' || owner||','|| TABLE||','|| COLUMN||' from ' || INSERTNAME || ' minus select owner, table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns@'|| LINK||'';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stringconsult || ';');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMMIT;');
        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE ALL;

    END;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE FIRST_SELECT;
END;
/
```

Comment: You can't use the contents of a variable as the name of a table. You'll need to use dynamic SQL. [Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011). Best of luck.

Comment: if the functionality is that of the example, you could simply declare the second loop as a stored procedure and pass tablename and link as parameters, plus you dont need to redeclare each variable on the loop, I'd suggest you declared them above with the others and just reassign  the values.

Comment: Do you mean the second look with only for and without cursor? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying with store procedure with a for but it gives that the table or view dont exits:  create or replace procedure differences (table in varchar2, link in varchar2)
  AS
   
  begin
    FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM table) LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(table);
    end loop;
  end;